# Estou com um problema no CardView para puxar em um layout no TabsAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

[image: layout inflado][image: reciclerview com lista]
Olá!Não consigo puxar meu CardView. 
Utilizo Tabs para a rolagem das paginas ficar mais facil. Ao invés de apenas puxar uma lista de coisas utilizando ReciclyerView, puxo os Layouts que criei. Dito isso, meu cardview na lista está populado, mas quando vou ver na pagina, ele não aparece ali. Como puxar os dados que já tenho no banco no cardview da tela principal?
(quero que a img2 (os cards) fiquem do msm jeito que ela, só que no layout que eu criei e inflei)

Comment: Não entendi nada, rs.

Comment: Eu preciso popular meu cardview. Eu utilizo um Layout nas Tabs.

Comment: Tem como postar uma screen do seu layout. Realmente não estou conseguindo visualizar o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Consegui colocar agora as imagens dos layouts